# How to 'define' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

First thing i'll say is that I know basically nothing about this, so a simple answer would be nice.

I installed a mod for Minecraft: Windows 10 and as I was trying to install the mod, I realized that there were multiple coding errors. So I went through, trying to fix what I could with memories of a coarse i did long ago. Eventually I came to an error that read: `'ModPE' is undefined`. ModPE happened to be a common variable, used in stuff like `ModPE.setItem` very often. How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, you can define the variable (`let ModPE = ...`) but the question is what do you define it to? We probably can't answer that without more details about the code

Comment: I thought Minecraft is written in Java ... though my experience with minecraft is pre microsoft owning it days, so I guess that may have changed (doubt it)

Comment: @JaromandaX The Regular Version is written in java. I'm playing on the windows 10 Edition which is written C++. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: And @Alex, I'm not sure about this. Maybe you could give me a hypothetical Example? I would still like to learn even if its not relevant.

Comment: Hmm, well it also depends on what language we're talking about here :) is the mod written in javascript or C++? Also, this question will probably be easier to answer if you can share the exact error message you see as well as some surrounding code there

Comment: java ... c++ ... yet the tag is javascript ... how is javascript relevant?

Comment: In order for us to help you, we will need to see some code that causes the error. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @JaromandaX Also, the language MineCraft itself is written in has no bearing here. The important question is what language does it support for mods. These don't have to be the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As you see the Define fix the constant value.

```
const ModPE = '';
```